# X keeps opening offscreen

Tags: macos, ssh, x11, xquartz

I am ssh-ing into my pi with

```
ssh pi@rpi.local -Y
```

in order to transmit an X window.
The window opens, but extremely far offscreen, I have to resize my screen multiple times randomly in order to make it visible.

**Question:** is it possible to move the window automatically

**or:** where do I set the standard X window position / offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With -geometry:

```
xterm -geometry +50+100
```

..positions a window 50 pixels from the left and 100 from the top. To specify the size:

```
xterm -geometry 400x300
```

...or combined:

```
xterm -geometry 400x300+50+100
```

Comment: it is being shown with a python opencv script. the code that shows it is
 `cv2.imshow("Frame", image)`, so I cannot control the position like that.

Comment: I'm sure you can pass the same geometry option to the python script; it should pass it on to the underlying X functions.

Comment: yup, found it, it is `cv2.movewindow()`. thank you very much